# Adding items to a php array without replacing the previous items

Tags: php, arrays

Am building a shopping cart and would like to append new items to a wishlist by adding them to a session but they shouldnt replace the existing items

This is what i have tried but returns an error of

```
[] operator not supported for strings
```

This is the code:

```
   public function addItem($value, (int)$id){
   if(isset($_SESSION[$value])){

        $_SESSION[$value][] = array();
        array_push($_SESSION[$value],array(
            'id'=>$id
        ));
        return true;
    }
}
```

The values of $value is a string

I have also followed on [This yii link](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4262-multi-dimensional-arrays-in-session/) and also on [This link](https://jaswanttak.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/php-associative-array-push/) but still am getting the same error

By doing it this way

```
   public function addItem($value, $id){
   if(isset($_SESSION[$value])){

        $_SESSION[$value] = array();
        array_push($_SESSION[$value],array(
            'id'=>$id
        ));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Adds the items but replaces whatever i had previously

WHAT DO I NEED TO CHANGE FOR IT TO WORK

Comment: what is $value? ur stock ? cause i would suggest u just use `$_SESSION['items'][] = Array($id,$value);`

Comment: _“Adds the items but replaces whatever i had previously”_ – of course it does, if you assign a new empty array to $_SESSION[$value] every time. // $_SESSION is an array already, and you don’t need to initialize “sub-arrays” in PHP, it will create them automatically. So you can simply use `$_SESSION[$value][] = 'new item';` to push new items into the array, the initialization with `$_SESSION[$value] = array()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error when attempting to use the short array push syntax on a string.   [demo here.](https://eval.in/683672)

`$_SESSION[$value]` is a string. so you cannot use something like `$_SESSION[$value][]= 's'`

So when the first time you use the `$_SESSION[$value]`, make it an array. Not a string. Then you can use as `$_SESSION[$value][]= 's';`